# IndexError Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

При работе с датасетом "titanic" столкнулся со следующей проблемой: необходимо выделить имя в зависимости от title пассажира, правила выделения разные, написал функцию:

```
def name_extract(x):
    title=x['Title']
    name=x['Name']
    if title in ['Mr','Miss']:
        return name.split('.')[1].split(' ')[1].strip()
    elif title in ['Mrs']:
        return name.split('(')[1].split(' ')[1].strip()
```

Первая часть функции для Mr и Miss работает без проблем, но вторая выдаёт ошибку

```
IndexError: ('list index out of range', 'occurred at index 20')
```

Датасет содержит поле `Name` - это полное имя пассажира, из которого необходимо выделить `First name`. Правила разные в зависимости от `Title`, к примеру для Mr пробелом, а для Mrs скобкой:

> Braund, Mr. Owen Harris, Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)

Title тоже выделяется по правилам и группируется. Этот этап решён без проблем

```
def name_extract(word):
    return word.split(',')[1].split('.')[0].strip()

def replace_titles(x):
    title=x['Title']
    if title in ['Don', 'Major', 'Capt', 'Jonkheer', 'Rev', 'Col', 'Master','Sir']:
        return 'Mr'
    elif title in ['Countess', 'Mme','Lady']:
        return 'Mrs'
    elif title in ['Mlle', 'Ms']:
        return 'Miss'
    elif title =='Dr':
        if x['Sex']=='Male':
            return 'Mr'
        else:
            return 'Mrs'
    else:
        return title
```

Comment: Можите по подробней о задаче? Что нужно писать в x? Что в списках `'Mr','Miss'`? Для решение требуется больше данных. Желательно по больше кода. Ошибка говорит, что где-то вы запросили у списка элемент по индексу, которого нет в списке.

Comment: Попробуйте привести в вопросе небольшой воспроизводимый пример данных и то, что вы хотите получить в итоге. [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: @MaxU дополнил кодом и пояснением в посте

Comment: @NewPythonProgrammist, да дополнил сведениями

Comment: Что вы хотите извлечь в случае с `'Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)'`?

Comment: @MaxU из всех Name нужно извлечь First Name, в конкретном случае это Lily, а в этом случае `Braund, Mr. Owen Harris` - это Owen

Answer (score 3):

Воспользуйтесь методом [Series.str.extract()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
train = pd.read_csv(r'C:\download\data\titanic\train.csv')

train[['Last','Title']] = (train['Name']
                           .str.extract(r'(\w+),\s*(\w+\.)', expand=True))

train['First'] = (train['Name']
                  .str.extract(r'\((\w+)\s*', expand=True)
                  .fillna(train['Name'].str.extract(r',\s*\w+\.\s*(\w+)\s*', expand=True)))
```

Результат:

```
In [40]: train[['Title','First','Last','Name']]
Out[40]:
       Title      First       Last                                               Name
0        Mr.       Owen     Braund                            Braund, Mr. Owen Harris
1       Mrs.   Florence    Cumings  Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Th...
2      Miss.      Laina  Heikkinen                             Heikkinen, Miss. Laina
3       Mrs.       Lily   Futrelle       Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)
4        Mr.    William      Allen                           Allen, Mr. William Henry
5        Mr.      James      Moran                                   Moran, Mr. James
6        Mr.    Timothy   McCarthy                            McCarthy, Mr. Timothy J
7    Master.      Gosta    Palsson                     Palsson, Master. Gosta Leonard
8       Mrs.  Elisabeth    Johnson  Johnson, Mrs. Oscar W (Elisabeth Vilhelmina Berg)
9       Mrs.      Adele     Nasser                Nasser, Mrs. Nicholas (Adele Achem)
..       ...        ...        ...                                                ...
881      Mr.     Johann     Markun                                 Markun, Mr. Johann
882    Miss.      Gerda   Dahlberg                       Dahlberg, Miss. Gerda Ulrika
883      Mr.  Frederick   Banfield                      Banfield, Mr. Frederick James
884      Mr.      Henry   Sutehall                             Sutehall, Mr. Henry Jr
885     Mrs.   Margaret       Rice               Rice, Mrs. William (Margaret Norton)
886     Rev.     Juozas   Montvila                              Montvila, Rev. Juozas
887    Miss.   Margaret     Graham                       Graham, Miss. Margaret Edith
888    Miss.  Catherine   Johnston           Johnston, Miss. Catherine Helen "Carrie"
889      Mr.       Karl       Behr                              Behr, Mr. Karl Howell
890      Mr.    Patrick     Dooley                                Dooley, Mr. Patrick

[891 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: с expand не запускается, но я поторопился, ошибку выдаёт, но при этом работает. Спасибо!

Comment: @AlexanderBotvin, какая у вас версия Pandas?

Comment: как это посмотреть?

Comment: @AlexanderBotvin, `pd.show_versions()`

Comment: версия pandas: 0.22.0

Comment: @AlexanderBotvin, скобка стояла не в том месте - сейчас исправил...

Comment: спасибо большое!

Comment: @AlexanderBotvin, пожалуйста. Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, [проголосуйте за ответ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow) и/или [отметьте его как решение](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)